# data.frame to list in R

Tags: r, list, transactions, dataframe

I have data like this:

```
ID   = c(rep("ID1",3), rep("ID2",2), "ID3", rep("ID4",2))
item = c("a","b","c","a","c","a","b","a")

df = data.frame(ID,item)

ID1 a
ID1 b
ID1 c
ID2 a
ID2 c
ID3 a
ID4 b
ID4 a
```

and I would need it as a list like this to be transformed to "transactions":

```
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"
[[2]]
[1] "a" "c"
[[3]]
[1] "a"
[[4]]
[1] "b" "a"
```

I tried:

```
lapply(split(item, ID), function(x) as.list(x))
```

but the items are still on separate "rows" and not one after the other.

Any ideas on how to accomplish the above format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `unstack`:

```
df <- data.frame(ID,item)
unstack(df, item~ID)
# $ID1
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
# 
# $ID2
# [1] "a" "c"
# 
# $ID3
# [1] "a"
# 
# $ID4
# [1] "b" "a"
```

Comment: Really nice function.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the expected output, you don't need to use `as.list`

```
setNames(split(as.character(df1$item),df1$ID) , NULL)
#[[1]]
#[1] "a" "b" "c"

#[[2]]
#[1] "a" "c"

#[[3]]
#[1] "a"

#[[4]]
#[1] "b" "a"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your approach and make it working:

```
> lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(u) u$item)
#$ID1
#[1] "a" "b" "c"

#$ID2
#[1] "a" "c"

#$ID3
#[1] "a"

#$ID4
#[1] "b" "a"
```

Comment: Not really since you used good trick "as.character" before splitting whereas I loop ...

Comment: Because the `df$item` was `factor` based on the input data showed by the OP.  If you use the same dataset, you would get `[1] a b c
Levels: a b c` (at least that is what I get on `R 3.1.2`)